# Distributing an Erlang Chat system

Tags: erlang, distributed, erlang-otp

I just finished Erlang in Practice screencasts (code [here](http://pragprog.com/screencasts/v-kserl/source_code)), and have some questions about distribution.

Here's the is overall architecture:

[image: architecture]

Here is how to the supervision tree looks like:

[image: supervisortree]

Reading [Distributed Applications](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/distributed_applications.html) leads me to believe that one of the primary motivations is for failover/takeover.

However, is it possible, for example, the Message Router supervisor and its workers to be on one node, and the rest of the system to be on another, without much changes to the code?

Or should there be 3 different OTP applications?

Also, how can this system be made to scale horizontally? For example if I realize now that my system can handle 100 users, and that I've identified the Message Router as the main bottleneck, how can I 'just add another node' where now it can handle 200 users?

Comment: What tool did you use to draw the top chart?

Comment: I didn't draw it, it's a screenshot from the screencast. But it's from OmniGaffle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've developed Erlang apps only during my studies, but generally we had many small processes doing only one thing and sending messages to other processes. And the beauty of Erlang is that it doesn't matter if you send a message within the same Erlang VM or withing the same Computer, same LAN or over the Internet, the call and the pointer to the other process looks always the same for the developer.

So you really want to have one application for every small part of the system.

That being said, it doesn't make it any simpler to construct an application which can scale out. A rule of thumb says that if you want an application to work on a factor of 10-times more nodes, you need to rewrite, since otherwise the messaging overhead would be too large. And obviously when you start from 1 to 2 you also need to consider it.

So if you found a bottleneck, the application which is particularly slow when handling too many clients, you want to run it a second time and than you need to have some additional load-balancing implemented, already before you start the second application.

Let's assume the supervisor checks the message content for inappropriate content and therefore is slow. In this case the node, everyone is talking to would be simple router application which would forward the messages to different instances of the supervisor application, in a round robin manner. In case those 1 or 2 instances are not enough, you could have the router written in a way, that you can manipulate the number of instances by sending controlling messages.

However for this, to work automatically, you would need to have another process monitoring the servers and discovering that they are overloaded or under utilized.

I know that dynamically adding and removing resources always sounds great when you hear about it, but as you can see it is a lot of work and you need to have some messaging system built which allows it, as well as a monitoring system which can monitor the need.

Hope this gives you some idea of how it could be done, unfortunately it's been over a year since I wrote my last Erlang application, and I didn't want to provide code which would be possibly wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I especially like the 2nd last paragraph. At least I'm not missing something obvious.

Comment: I didn't - I had erlang doing all of this, since it was only small assignments. Generally Erlang and TCP can do a lot of things, if it isn't enough for you, you have to implement an additional system on top of your application which detects network and node failures.